# What is the way to display the documents only in 'recent files' (Nautilus/Files) on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: gnome, 20.04, nautilus

I would like 'recent files' to display only the opened/accessed 'documents'.
No music, video, images, ...
It was easily configurable on 16.04 but didn't find a way on 20.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no control. An [issue about this problem](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/issues/1444) was closed, pointing to a location to raise issues on the Settings dialog.

Failing that, you still can quickly filter the recent files by typing a file extension, or some characters of the file name.